# Как привязать ObservableCollection<Image> к FlexLayout в Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Имеется FlexLayout

```xml
<FlexLayout x:Name="flexLayout" Wrap="Wrap" JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly" />
```

Как к нему привязать ObservableCollection ?

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Image> ImageCollection { get; set; }
            
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
                
        ImageCollection = new ObservableCollection<Image>();
                
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            ImageCollection.Add(new Image { Source = "waterfront.jpg" });
        }
    }
}
```

Спасибо за ваше время.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Так как я вообще ничего не знаю про Xamarin и никогда не писал под эту платформу, а писал под WPF, а системы похожите, то я попробую просто угадать ответ читая документацию и примеры из гугла.*

Первое, что вам надо сделать - это перестать создавать контролы к коде, а оставить эту работу самому UI движку.

Так же стоит иметь настроенным `BindingContext`. Вот [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics), но несмотря на то что я в теме про привязки данных, я мало что понял. :)

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

```cs
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Images { get; }
            
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Images = new ObservableCollection<string>();
                
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Images.Add("waterfront.jpg");
        }
    }
}
```

Если вы хотите динамически менять строки, а не только добавлять и удалять элементы коллекции, то придется реализовать вьюмодель с данными для картинки (см. MVVM и `INotifyPropertyChanged`). Но конкретно для данного примера это не обязательно.

Теперь осталось объяснить интерфейсу, что от него требуется.

```xml
<FlexLayout Wrap="Wrap"
            JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly"
            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image>
                <Image.Source>
                    <FileImageSource File="{Binding}" />
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</FlexLayout>
```

Про картинки тоже есть [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows).

Можно еще так попробовать, во всяком случае в WPF так можно.

```xml
<Image Source="{Binding}" />
```

Comment: 'BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"  '   здесь пишет **Не найден контекст данных для привязки **

Comment: @mdlcode исправил код в конструкторе

Comment: До сих пор проблема остается.

Comment: @mdlcode оно запускается и ругается, или не запускается? Может глюки, попробуйте закрыть ide, удалить папки bin и obj (картинку сохраните) и запуститься заново.

Comment: оно запускается. Попробовал удалить bin and obj и в главном проекте и в андроиде, но нет не помогло.

Comment: @mdlcode Запускается, а работает как надо, или пусто на экране?

Comment: @mdlcode а если вместо конструктора присвоить контекст в xaml `BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=This}"` в параметрах Page.

Comment: На экране пусто. Но чтобы проверить. что все работает я с помощью горячей перезагрузки XAML в** FlexLayout** добавляю картинку **<Image Source="waterfront.jpg"/>** и всё работает

Comment: сбрасывает исключение **Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 6:14. Can not find the object referenced by This' **

Comment: @mdlcode обновил код в ответе, создайте отдельный класс для привязок.

Comment: все получилось.                                                                                          
1.Как вы думаете почему нужно было создать отдельный класс для привязок?                       2. **Первое, что вам надо сделать - это перестать создавать контролы к коде, а оставить эту работу самому UI движку.** А как еще можно кроме как в коде?

Comment: @mdlcode 1) думаю, что это причуды привязок в Xamarin. В WPF и так и сяк и наперекосяк работает. 2) В ответе не создается ни одного контрола в C# коде, все делает View (XAML).